# Add property to ProductVariationType via hook_entity_type_build()

Tags: 8, entities, commerce, hooks

Hy guys,

I'm trying to implement a simple stock management in my e-commerce. The ProductVariation will have a `stock_quantity` field used to track product availability.

I would like that `stock_quantity` field is shown only if user checks an `enable_stock_management` checkbox on ProductVariation bundle edit page. I.e. */admin/commerce/config/product-variation-types/default/edit*

In other words I would like to mimic **Submission form settings**, **Menu settings**, **Display settings** functionalities of Node's bundles.

By Google-ing a bit I think that `hook_entity_type_build()` is the hook to use. But, once I'm in the hook what I'm supposed to do in order to add the property I need and display it in the edit form?

```
 /**
  * Implements hook_entity_type_build().
  */
 function commerce_warehouse_entity_type_build(array &$entity_types) {
     /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface[] $entity_types */
     $entity_types['commerce_product_variation_type']-> # ... And now?;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ends up that `hook_entity_type_build()` is not the right way to implement what I want. I found a solution usign `ThirdPartySettingsInterface`, which every `ConfigEntityBase` implements.

First I've altered `ProductVariationType` form via `hook_form_alter()` in order to add a checkbox to the form and register a new `#enity_builder`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  /** @var ProductVariationTypeInterface $entity */
  $entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();

  $form['warehouse_management'] = [
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Enable warehouse management'),
    '#default_value' => $entity->getThirdPartySetting('commerce_warehouse', 'warehouse_management'),
  ];

  $form['#entity_builders'][] = 'MY_MODULE_entity_ENTITY_ID_builder';
}
```

Then I've defined my custom entity builder function where I register my third party setting. Pretty simple! This [article](https://www.webomelette.com/drupal-8-custom-data-configuration-entities-using-thirdpartysettingsinterface) helps me out a lot.

```
/**
 * Entity builder for commerce_product_variation_type entity.
 */
function MY_MODULE_entity_ENTITY_ID_builder($entity_type, ProductVariationTypeInterface $entity, &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $entity->setThirdPartySetting('commerce_warehouse', 'warehouse_management', $form_state->getValue('warehouse_management'));
}
```